# Mosquitto Broker is receving data partially

Tags: c, mqtt, gprs

I am trying to send a connect packet to the mosquitto MQTT broker. I can establish the connection with broker, but the broker is not completely receiving connect data i.e. wireshark doesnt show MQIspd data in the broker but receiving client ID.

MQTT protocl version is v3.0.

Sending packet via SIM900 GSM/GPRS modem.

What is wrong with the code?

Below is  connect packet C code:

```
#define MQTTCONNECT 1<<4
#define MQTTPUBLISH 3<<4
#define KEEPALIVE 15000

int main()
{
    uint8_t buf[255];
    char *id="MQTT"
    uint8_t var_header[] = {0x00,0x06,0x4d,0x51,0x49,0x73,0x64,0x70,0x03,0x02,0x00,KEEPALIVE/500,0x00,strlen(id);
    uint8_t fixed_header[] = {MQTTCONNECT,12+strlen(id)+2};
    char packet[sizeof(fixed_header)+sizeof(var_header)+strlen(id)];

    memset(packet,0,sizeof(packet));
    memcpy(packet,fixed_header,sizeof(fixed_header));
    //memcpy(packet+sizeof(fixed_header),var_header,sizeof(var_header));
    //memcpy(packet+sizeof(fixed_header)+sizeof(var_header),id,strlen(id));
    //sprintf(buf,"%s\x1A",memcpy(packet+sizeof(fixed_header)+sizeof(var_header),id,strlen(id));
    sprintf(buf,"%s\x1A",memcpy(packet+sizeof(fixed_header)+sizeof(var_header),id,strlen(id)));
    port_write(buf); //write data into the serial port.
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your `port_write(buf)` will write data from the `packet` variable starting at `packet[sizeof(fixed_header)+sizeof(var_header)]`. This is what the `sprintf()` call is copying to `buf` and is certainly not what you want. I don't think there is a need to have both a `packet` and a `buf` variable, just use one of them and I think it will simplify matters.

Try this instead:

```
int main()
{
    char *id="MQTT"
    uint8_t var_header[] = {0x00, 0x06, 0x4d, 0x51, 0x49, 0x73, 0x64, 0x70, 0x03, 0x02, 0x00, KEEPALIVE/500, 0x00, strlen(id);
    uint8_t fixed_header[] = {MQTTCONNECT, 12+strlen(id)+2};
    char packet[sizeof(fixed_header)+sizeof(var_header)+strlen(id) + 2];

    memset(packet, 0, sizeof(packet));
    memcpy(packet, fixed_header, sizeof(fixed_header));
    memcpy(packet+sizeof(fixed_header), var_header, sizeof(var_header));
    sprintf(packet+sizeof(fixed_header)+sizeof(var_header), "%s\x1A", id);

    port_write((uint8_t *)packet); //write data into the serial port.

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. The reason i used sprintf  is i want to send the data into serial so i need to write the data along with "x1A" string. I cant simply give 'port_write(packet);'.

Comment: The point is that your sprintf call means you end up sending the wrong data. sprintf itself isn't to blame, it's just the data in the wrong place.

Comment: Thanks @ralight. Im facing another problem here. In 'var_header' array `0x00` value creates problem. When i remove that value from that array and run the code, broker receives 'MQIsdp'. Otherwise no data is receiving at the broker.

Comment: That's a problem with port_write() then by the sounds of things, it needs to accept a "length" parameter as well. You can't legitimately remove the 0x00 values.

Comment: Hi @ralight. I just tried to print the unit8_t values with 0x00 value and without 0x00 value.                                                                                     `uint8_t packet[]={0x4d,0x51,0x49};
    printf((uint8_t*)packet); Output: MQI`                                                  `uint8_t packet[]={0x00,0x4d,0x51,0x49};
    printf((uint8_t*)packet); Output: none` Also i tried with printf specifier "%u", no use cant get exact data.

Comment: This isn't the place for a discussion really, but the point is that `printf()` and presumably `port_write()` assume a string terminated by a zero. If your string starts with a zero, then they will assume there is no data to print. You need to use a different function to output the data. `fwrite()` allows you to specify the length of data you are writing, for example.

Answer (score 1):

As @ralight said, with the memcpy inside sprintf, you are copying into buf only the payload of the message (you aren't copying fixed header and variable header) and in this case the payload contains only the client ID.
However I agree with @ralight ... two "buffers" aren't useful.